# How to get the LineStrings from a MultiLineString

Tags: geotools, linestring, splitting

I was wondering if there is a way I can extract the LineStrings from a MultiLinestring object.
What I am really trying to do is look into a MultiLineString  and see if I have a certain LineString. I have been looking everywhere, and the only method that sounds like it can do something of that sort is ***contains(Geometry g)***  but that does not do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use [ST_GeometryN](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_GeometryN.html)

eg,

```
select st_astext(st_geometryn(st_geomfromtext(
 'MULTILINESTRING ((10 10, 20 20, 10 40),(40 40, 30 30, 40 20, 30 10))'),1));
```

yields

`LINESTRING(10 10,20 20,10 40)`.

Note, the indexing is based off 1.

You could also loop through each one and test for equality, using generate_series to create the indexes, eg,

```
select st_equals(st_geometryn(g.geom, x), 
    st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(40 40, 30 30, 40 20, 30 10)')) 
from 
    (select st_geomfromtext('MULTILINESTRING ((10 10, 20 20, 10 40),
        (40 40, 30 30, 40 20, 30 10))') as geom ) g, 
    generate_series(1,2) x;
```

returns f, t.

You would probably want to use ST_NumGeometries(geom) instead of 2 in generate_series, but you get the idea.

Comment: Perhaps GeoTools does not support SQL but question does not require it either in any other place than tags.

Comment: Thanks, actually i am using java for this, but your answer gave me an idea and it worked.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad, I was in Postgis mode yesterday and totally overlooked the tag. But, the same principle works in code, as you have discovered.

Comment: @user3253067 I want to solve the same problem with geoTools, but the PostGIS idea did not help me. Would be great if you could provide your solution

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it is quite easy, just use `.getGeometryN()`

Some Example:

`GeometryJSON gjson = new GeometryJSON();
Reader fileReader = new FileReader('<geoJsonFilePath>');
MultiLineString mls = gjson.readMultiLine( fileReader );
LineString ls = mls.getGeometryN(1)); // Gives you the first linestring`